# hover element if another element is hovered

Tags: html, css

I've looked around but can't find the right answer for this... How do I set an element to hover, assuming another is hovered?

Where Assuming "selector" is hovered, it will hover, box 1+2 etc...

http://jsfiddle.net/wgJRQ/

```
<div id="table">
<div id="row">
    <div id="selector">selector 1</div>
    <div id="selector2">selector 2</div>
</div>
<br />
<div id="row">
    <div id="box1">box 1</div>
    <div id="box2">box 2</div>
</div>
<div id="row">
    <div id="box3">box 3</div>
    <div id="box4">box 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot have more than one element with the same ID

Comment: I CAN use it, but I have no idea what code would be needed/used.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
#box1:hover, #box1:hover~#box2 {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border:2px solid #666666;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wgJRQ/2/)

Comment: it is the [sibling selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector)

Comment: That works great, thanks! But for some reason, if I modify it, so that it's in the selector box, to hover, anything but the second selector box (selector2), it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery:

```
$('#table > div:first > div')
    .hover(function() {
        $('#table').children('div')
            .eq($(this).index() + 1)
            .children('div')
            .toggleClass('active');
        return false;
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/pyY5u/

You might want to optimize your hover states and reduce it to a single declaration, something like this:

```
#table > div:nth-child(n+1) > div {
    border:2px solid #FFFFFF;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100px;
}
#table > div:nth-child(n+1) > div:hover,
#table > div:nth-child(n+1) > div.active {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border:2px solid #666666;
}
#box1, #box2 {
    background-color:#E07586;
}
#box3, #box4 {
    background-color:#837C71;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With CSS you can only do it if the "target" element is inside the one being hovered.

In your case, you should change your layout to be arranged in columns instead of rows, so that you have box 1 and box 2 ***inside*** selector 1. That way you can change the look of box1 when you hover on its selector: `.selector:hover .box1 {...}`

If you cannot do this, then you will have to use Javascript.

Keep in mind that you cannot trigger `:hover` with Javascript, you will have to add a class to the boxes when the mouse enters the selectors, and remove the class when it exits them.